# Why do I get false "new users" positives in Crashlytics/Answers?

Tags: crashlytics

Occasionally, Crashlytics/Answers tell me that a lot of "new users" downloaded my app. However, this is not what Apple tells me the next day when presenting their download stats. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to me running my app in the simulator. Each such run is interpreted as a new installation by Crashlytics/Answers and that's their definition of "new user".

Here's how I solved this:

```
#if !TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
#endif
```